# TypeError: Cannot perform 'get' on a proxy that has been revoked

Tags: node.js, botframework

I am trying to use context in cron.schedule()

```
        this.onTeamsMembersAddedEvent(async (membersAdded, teamInfo, turnContext, next) => {
        const members = await TeamsInfo.getTeamMembers(turnContext);
        const channels = await TeamsInfo.getTeamChannels(turnContext);
        const teamDetails = await TeamsInfo.getTeamDetails(turnContext);
        let msteam = await msTeamsWorkspace.findOne({
            teamName: teamDetails.name,
            teamID: teamDetails.id,
            channelID: channels[0].id
        });

        cron.schedule("* * * * * *", async function(){
            var manager_detail = await Users.findById('5edb94e1182d254d5055775e')
            turnContext.activity.conversation.id = manager_detail.conversationId;
            await turnContext.sendActivity("Hey you got it");
        });

        await next();
    });
```

Error :

```
TypeError: Cannot perform 'get' on a proxy that has been revoked
    at Task.execution (K:\Project\MSTeams Bot\src\bot\bot.js:187:29)
    at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:97:5)
```

Line 187: 
turnContext.activity.conversation.id = manager_detail.conversationId;

Comment: Were you able to get this working with my answer? If so, please "accept" and upvote it so others can quickly find the answer and I can clear this from my support tracker. If not, let me know how else I can help!

Comment: Hey, can you answer this one too https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62953661/onteamsmemberaddedevent-not-working-for-personal-scope

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Basically, this happens because `context` only exists until you call `next()`, so once the message is sent, the proxy that the bot uses is no longer available. This makes using callbacks, `setInterval`, `setTimeout`, and `cron` a bit tricky to use. The recommended route is to use [Proactive Messages](https://github.com/microsoft/BotBuilder-Samples/tree/master/samples/javascript_nodejs/16.proactive-messages).

The key steps are to:

1. Save the bot adapter somewhere that you can use it. The sample does so [here](https://github.com/microsoft/BotBuilder-Samples/blob/master/samples/javascript_nodejs/16.proactive-messages/index.js#L71), but it also lives in `turnContext.adapter` (see below)
2. Save a `conversationReference` that you can refer back to. The sample does so [here](https://github.com/microsoft/BotBuilder-Samples/blob/master/samples/javascript_nodejs/16.proactive-messages/bots/proactiveBot.js#L33)
3. Use the `adapter` and `conversationReference` to send a proactive message using `continueConversation`. The sample does so [here](https://github.com/microsoft/BotBuilder-Samples/blob/master/samples/javascript_nodejs/16.proactive-messages/index.js#L71)

Exactly how you do that is up to you and the use case for your bot. But here's a quick code sample to show it works with `cron`:

```js
const { ActivityHandler, MessageFactory, TurnContext } = require('botbuilder');
const cron = require('node-cron');

var conversationReferences = {};
var adapter;

class EchoBot extends ActivityHandler {
    constructor() {
        super();
        // See https://aka.ms/about-bot-activity-message to learn more about the message and other activity types.
        this.onMessage(async (context, next) => {
            const replyText = `Echo: ${ context.activity.text }`;
            await context.sendActivity(MessageFactory.text(replyText, replyText));

            const currentUser = context.activity.from.id;
            conversationReferences[currentUser] = TurnContext.getConversationReference(context.activity);
            adapter = context.adapter;

            cron.schedule('* * * * * *', async function() {
                await adapter.continueConversation(conversationReferences[currentUser], async turnContext => {
                    await turnContext.sendActivity('proactive hello');
                });
            });
            // By calling next() you ensure that the next BotHandler is run.
            await next();
        });
[...]
```