# onTeamsMemberAddedEvent() not working for personal scope

Tags: node.js, botframework, microsoft-graph-api, microsoft-teams

I was using Microsoft graph API for installing the bot for a user [https://graph.microsoft.com/beta/users/{userID}/teamwork/installedApps](https://graph.microsoft.com/beta/users/%7BuserID%7D/teamwork/installedApps)

On installing the bot, onTeamsMemberAddedEvent() was called for the personal scope as well as for teams scope and through that, I was sending the welcome message to the users.
Apart from graph api, I was also installing the bot directly and the function was getting revoked.

But now, this event is not getting called and I am unable to get conversationId from the personal scope of a user. It is working for teamscope only.

Comment: @StevenKanberg, has provided the accurate solution.

Answer (score 2):

When a conversation is started between you and another user, that conversation is persisted for all future dialogs regardless of when they occur. The same is true when you start a conversation with a bot. A solitary conversation is created that is persisted for as long as you and the bot exist within the Teams tenant.

It is because of this that the `onTeamsMemberAddedEvent()` is only called once in a personal scope. It only occurs when the initial conversation occurs and the conversation is created. After that point, any future dialogs with the bot are treated as an extension of the first conversation.